Sagemath substitute on the fly while plotting
I would like to plot CDF with multiple parameters, but running into errors beyond one variable.
x=var('x')
a_hat=var('a_hat')
beta_c=var('beta_c')
G = RealDistribution('gaussian', 1)
def Φ(x, a_hat, beta_c): return G.cum_distribution_function(ln(x/a_hat)/beta_c)

How do I do these substitutions on the fly?
plot(Φ,(x,0, 3),axes_labels=['$g$','$cdf$'], frame=True, ymin=0, ymax=1) # a_hat = 1
plot(Φ,(x,0, 3),axes_labels=['$g$','$cdf$'], frame=True, ymin=0, ymax=1) # a_hat = 2

I run into the following error:
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

